# Android EdgeToEdgeStoreList doesn't work [property onClick is not a function]

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a edgeToEdge List and when the user click on the item, call a function.
In the browser all works perfectlly, but on android emulator no.

The html:

```
<ul id="ulElencoListiniClienti"></ul>
```

The js:

```
        var mydata="[ ";
        for (var i=0;i<codice_listino.length;i++){
            mydata+="{ 'label': '"+codice_listino[i].CDLST+"', 'onClick': \"getAllDettaglioListino('"+codice_listino[i].CDLST+"')\"  }, ";

        }
        var lungh = mydata.length;
        mydata = mydata.substring(0,lungh-2); // tolgo l'ultimo carattere della stringa,ovvero la virgola

        mydata+="] ";
listini_cliente_data= eval (mydata);
```

The function getAllDettaglioListino(id_listino)

```
function getAllDettaglioListino(id_listino){
..
    WL.Logger.debug("Dettaglio listino:"+id_listino);
..      
var w =  dijit.registry.byId('view_elenco_listini');
    w.performTransition('view_dettaglio_listini',1,"slide",null);
```

The logcat error:

```
07-02 12:31:41.511: D/CordovaLog(753): Uncaught TypeError: Property 'onClick' of object [Widget dojox.mobile.ListItem, dojox_mobile_ListItem_39] is not a function

07-02 12:31:41.511: E/Web Console(753): Uncaught TypeError: Property 'onClick' of object [Widget dojox.mobile.ListItem, dojox_mobile_ListItem_39] is not a function at file:///data/data/com.MobileACG/files/www/default/dojo/mobile-ui-layer.js:302
```

nobody has ever used the property onClick on a EdgeToEdgeStoreList and test it in Android environment?

[image: EdgeToEdgeList]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure that onclick is supposed to point to a function itself.  So you will have to wrap it.

```
'onClick': \"function(){getAllDettaglioListino('"+codice_listino[i].CDLST+"')}\"
```

Comment: Sure?It's strange because on browser it works!And getAllDettaglioListino(param) is a function

Comment: "SyntaxError: function statement requires a name." : It doesn't work neither on a browser

Comment: did you try setting moveto:'#'  or setting clickable:true

Comment: I need to call that function. Then from that function, I do the MoveTo(perfomTransition)

Comment: The moveto:'#' does not actually move anywhere but it makes lists clickable. So you can have the onClick="function" and moveto:'#'

Comment: Add errors on question.  Uncaught TypeError: Property 'onClick' of object

Comment: nobody has ever used the property onClick on a EdgeToEdgeStoreList?

Comment: Property 'onClick' of object [Widget dojox.mobile.ListItem, dojox_mobile_ListItem_39] is not a function.  What that error is saying is that onClick expects a function. not a function call.  so you  have to wrap it in an anonymous function like i do im my code. ex.<li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" data-dojo-props="moveTo:'#',onClick:function(){accountController.getOpenOrders()}">Open Orders</li>